# Storyboards: auto layout for different device screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Firstly I am begginer with ios.I have a problem which different iphone models  the screen(stroyboard) is not fit regularly .I was formed  storyboard  by compact with Base values(e.g 3.5 4 4.7 inch).İt is good  on iphone 6 simulator but iphone 5 or iphone 4 it be small and the view objects  sliped out of screen.What am i do?,is there any  way to overcome this with easily ?I want to  screen(storyboard) is fitted regularly on above iphone 4 models.

[İphone 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr7uA.png)
[iphone 6s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwpvf.png)

Comment: It really depends upon your desired user interface. Without being able to see that it is hard to answer this. Perhaps post a screenshot.

Comment: You need to learn autolayout & size classes, follow the [storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1)

Comment: We need to see your constraints. The whole point of auto layout is being able to resize views based on their relation to the views around them and their superview. If you are doing that properly they should resize with no issue. If you hard code the height/width, then you're not utilizing the tool properly to do what you want to do.

Comment: thank you all,I edit and instered pictures ,Tableview is not fit

Answer (score 0):

you need to used constraints the put the object Relatively at the views .
you need to read how to used constraints.